# Access Androids Traffic statistics

Tags: android, traffic

I would like to monitor the traffic of my mobile hotspot.

I found `TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes` but this won't let me monitor precisely the usage of the android mobile hotspot function (or any other app). How can I access the statistic of the **data usage** menue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes but this won't let me monitor precisely the usage of the android mobile hotspot function (or any other app).

`TrafficStats` have other methods -- such as `getUidTxBytes()` -- that let you monitor traffic by UID, which roughly equates to app. However, it may require some experimentation for you to determine what exactly will contain "the android mobile hotspot function", and it is not out of the question that this is not covered by `TrafficStats`, at least at the UID level.

You are welcome to examine [the AOSP Settings app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) to see how the data usage screen is implemented, though I suspect nothing in there is visible to you in the Android SDK other than `TrafficStats`.

Comment: hi there, thank you for your answer. any idea how I can find the "thethering & mobile internet" uid?

Comment: @Goot: Take a set of `TrafficStats` readings across all UIDs and record the values. Do a whole bunch of tethered Internet work. Check the `TrafficStats` readings again. The UID with the big uptick in data transfer presumably is the UID covering tethering.

Comment: I found 'TrafficStats.UID_TETHERING' which is unfortunately not visible. I guess I have to do this the hard way. Thanks. Is it highly probable that the UID will change for different android versions?

Comment: @Goot: "Is it highly probable that the UID will change for different android versions?" -- well, device manufacturers have the right to tinker, so I would not assume a fixed value.

Comment: @Goot - Did u tried it ? When i tried it, i got no results using the "TrafficStats.UID_TETHERING" the hard way. Its a constant just for the AOSP Settings app.